# Flex, pushing message, ServiceAdapter, BlazeDS

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, push-notification, blazeds

I have Flex 3.6A + BlazeDS + java6 webapp.

I want to push message from server that must be intercepted by the client (.mxml page). Googlin around I manage to build the follow example:

```
public class TestMessaging extends ServiceAdapter {

private String previousMsg = "";
private volatile boolean running;

private Message createTestMessage() {
    AsyncMessage msg = new AsyncMessage();
    msg.setDestination("RandomDataPush");
    msg.setClientId(UUIDUtils.createUUID());
    msg.setMessageId(UUIDUtils.createUUID());
    msg.setBody(BarValues.STATUS);

    return msg;
}

@Override
public void start(){    
    super.start();

    Thread messageSender = new Thread(){
        public void run(){
            running = true;
            while(running){
                sendMessageToClients(createTestMessage());
                secondsToSleep(3);
            }
        }
    };

    messageSender.start();        
}
/**
 * @see flex.messaging.services.ServiceAdapter#stop()
 */
@Override
public void stop(){
    super.stop();
    running = false;
}

public void sendMessageToClients(Message msg) {
    if (!msg.getBody().equals(previousMsg)) {
        previousMsg = msg.getBody().toString();
        ((MessageService) getDestination().getService()).pushMessageToClients(msg, false);
    }
}

@Override
public Object invoke(Message message) {
    if (message.getBody().equals("stop")) {
        running = false;
    } else if (message.getBody().equals("start")) {
        start();
    }
    return null;
}

private void secondsToSleep(int seconds) {
    try{
        Thread.sleep(seconds * 1000);
    }catch(InterruptedException e){
        System.out.println("TestServiceAdapter Interrupted while sending messages");
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}        

}
```

In the .mxml I have:

```
<mx:Application xmlns:mx="http://www.adobe.com/2006/mxml" layout="absolute" width="100%" height="100%" creationComplete="init()">

<mx:Script>
    <![CDATA[
      private function messageHandler(message:IMessage):void {
         randomNumbers = message.body as String;
         if (randomNumbers == null) {
         var msg:AsyncMessage = new AsyncMessage();
         msg.body = "stop";
         producer.send(msg);
    } else Alert.show(randomNumbers.toString());
 }

private function init():void {
   var msg:AsyncMessage = new AsyncMessage();

   msg.body = "stop";
   producer.send(msg);
   consumer.subscribe();
}

private function start():void {
   var msg:AsyncMessage = new AsyncMessage();

   msg.body = "start";
   producer.send(msg);
   consumer.subscribe();
}

private function handleFault(event:MessageFaultEvent):void {
   Alert.show(event.faultString);
}

private function ack(event:MessageAckEvent):void {
   if (event.message.body != null) {
      randomNumbers = event.message.body as String;
      Alert.show(randomNumbers.toString());
   }
}

<mx:Producer id="producer" destination="RandomDataPush" acknowledge="ack(event)"/>
<mx:Consumer id="consumer" destination="RandomDataPush" message="messageHandler(event.message)" />

</mx:Application>
```

Problems are:

1) Whitout a thread I can't manage to push messages

2) The thread starts automatically when I alunch the application. To prevent this I send the "stop" when the init() method of the flex page is called (but is really orrible)

What I want to do is: when a java query is executed (or a complex elaboration starts) I want to start the service and send messages calling manually the *sendMessageToClients* method (without thread if is it possible) and, when the query or the elaboration ends, stop the service.

Can you help me?
Thanks all